# They cheerleaded for it? or cheerled?

Tags: past-participles, compounds

Is this the best way to conjugate "cheerlead"?

> they cheerleaded for it just the same

"Cheerlead" becomes unrecognizable when you say "they ***cheerled***", so I'm guessing this is why you don't conjugate it like "lead", but I cannot find any references that include conjugation of the verb. This is not the same issue as found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18926/how-can-i-change-the-tense-of-a-hyphenated-verb), since it's not about the placement of the suffix, but rather the choice of suffix.

EDIT:
I think @KristinaLopez is correct, if you're speaking about literal cheerleaders, although the [context here](http://ace.mu.nu/archives/341490.php) is more figurative, casting the media as "cheerleaders". If you say the media "cheered", it doesn't have the same connotation of "leading the cheering for". I suppose though "cheered" still is correct in that case, and you'd need to recast the sentence to get the word "cheerleader" into it, such as:

> ..., and yet they acted as cheerleaders for it just the same

Comment: They lead the cheering squad for it just the same.

Comment: Neither. _Cheerleading_ comes from _cheerleader_, an agent noun; _cheerleading_ is defined as what _cheerleaders_ do. As a verb with incorporated object, it doesn't inflect well: _*I housepainted for two months this summer,_ _*She lawnmowed for a couple of hours before her nap,_ _*He cheerled for two weeks before they kicked him off the squad._

Comment: Cheerleaders *cheer*.  "They *cheered* for it just the same."

Comment: Isn't it valid to make a verb out of any noun just like "to milk (a cow)"? If yes, why cannot one use "they cheerleadered"?

Comment: @glagolig  Only if one insists on glagoligging.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3060/8019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how definitive a source it is considered, but wiktionary does give this formation as *cheerleaded*.

[Wiktionnary:Cheerlead](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheerlead)

Nonetheless, I agree it would be better to choose a different construction, choosing clarity over pedantry. However I think care needs to be taken here. You could chose:

"... they led the cheer just the same."

However, I'm not sure that really means quite the same. One can lead a cheer without being a cheerleader. I understand from your edit that the context is metaphorical, nonetheless, the above eliminates the metaphor, and so looses some of the original intent. Further:

"... they cheered just the same."

Doesn't mean the same thing at all. A cheerleader does not just cheer, s/he LEADS the cheers of others, partly by cheering herself/himself.

"... the were cheerleaders for it just the same."

While clunky is probably the closest I can get, conveying the sense, and retaining the metaphor.

Answer (score 4):

John Lawler is correct.

*Cheerled* is indeed very awkward to say.

A great choice, though perhaps inappropriate in tone, would be *led cheer.*

Comment: Sometimes the infelicitous choice is just the right option. This is about human expression, not mathematics or programming.

Comment: And if *cheerled* seems strange, mayby try spelling it *cheer-led*.

Comment: Big +1, came to say the same ("led cheer").  Was also going to support *cheerled* precisely because of the potential mispronunciation.  But practically, @GEdgar makes a good point as does JL.

Comment: Actually, if you don't want to sound so strange, you could say "they were responsible for cheerleading."

Answer (score 3):

We have a tendency in English to create useful single words out of two other words which are not necessarily the same part of speech as the *resulting* word.

In the case under discussion, we are considering the common tendency to create a *noun* out of two *connected verbs* that represent the function of the person then designated by the resulting noun. The unfortunate part is this: We then often try to create a sort of *back formation* from the resulting noun as if it were a verb. In this particular case, *cheerleader* was created out of *cheer* and *leader* (well, duh), meaning a person who leads the cheers in support of a team while they are playing a game against another team (and at pep rallies). Then, my goodness, here we are, trying to use *cheerleader* as a version of the imaginary verb *cheerlead*, and subsequently trying to conjugate *cheerlead*.

*Cheerlead* is not a verb. *Cheerlead* is not even a word. It doesn't exist. Give it up, friends.

You can lead cheers, or you can cheer. Conjugate either of those, if you like. I hope this helps.

Comment: I personally like this answer best of all, but must admit that @Fraser Orr actually did find a reference for the verb that includes the past tense(s).

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Neither. *Cheerleading* comes from *cheerleader*, an agent noun; *cheerleading* is defined as what *cheerleaders* do. As a verb with incorporated object, it doesn't inflect well: **I housepainted for two months this summer,* **She lawnmowed for a couple of hours before her nap,* **He cheerled for two weeks before they kicked him off the squad.*